# Selenium and testng Assertion

Tags: selenium, testng

Help please
How to assertequal tow string with testNG
String1 with lowercase and string 2 uppercase
Exp: String1 hello world
String1 HELLO world

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to understand your question. Maybe you could explain the problem better.

If you want to **compare two strings in case-insensitive style**, you could do like this in your assertion:

```
assertEquals(str1.toUpperCase(), str2.toUpperCase());
```